# Debian Dual Boot GRUB not showing properly

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 + Kali and I've followed all the steps from Kali's doc for setting up dual boot. The thing is, after many reinstallations I'm still having the same problem.

What I've done:
Install Ubuntu first
Boot from Kali's live image, made a partition for it and then installed it.

When I boot my computer, GRUB goes to Ubuntu's grub.cfg instead of Kali's. And from there I have to press either 'c' or 'esc' and go to GRUB cli and run these commands, over and over again for getting Kali's grub to show up:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

I'm fine with the workaround, but it's becoming very tedious... Once I run these commands on grub CLI I'm able to get to Kali's GRUB and it shows Kali + Ubuntu and from there I can choose. If I don't run these commands it would only boot Ubuntu's GRUB which doesn't show Kali.

I've also tried navigating to `/boot/efi/EFI/` and there I can see three folders: BOOT, kali and ubuntu. When I navigate to `ubuntu` I can see there's a `grub.cfg` file, but `kali` hasn't got one even though I have tried manually tweaking `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub` after changing the file, which doesn't generate the grub.cfg file. I've also tried creating `grub.cfg` manually for Kali, but I'm still stuck...

It's my first time installing two linux systems in my machine, so apologies in advance if I'm not that specific with my problem.

Thanks in advance,
Rico.

Answer (score 2):

to get Kali in the Ubuntu Bootloader simply try on your installed ubuntu: `sudo update-grub` it should detect kali and you should be able to boot kali from the ubuntu Bootloader.

Comment: I've already tried doing this from Ubuntu. It doesn't fix the issue... I still need to run GRUB cli to pull out Kali's GRUB which allows me to choose between Kali and Ubuntu, any more ideas?

Comment: look in your bios and swtich in boot option  legacy-first instead Efi, maybe Kali is not as efi-system installed, and not shown because of that. Instead Ubuntu-Grub loader the Kali Bootloader should come up first.

Comment: I've tried switching to legacy boot but it has not fixed the problem. I guess I will be using my workaround whenever I need to boot Kali, thanks anyways for trying to help me mate.